# Rails does not recognize Patch request method, but PUT works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm probably just not noticing some small simple detail. But if I have an object Backbone model : `$.object`, and I save it as :

```
$.object.save({'correct': 1})
```

This works fine as a `PUT` request.

However, if I do :

```
$.object.save({'correct': 1}, {patch: true});
```

Then it delivers a PATCH request to the same URL, but returns a 404, URL not found..

I can't wrap my head around this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What does `rake routes` say? Does it list the PATCH route for your action as expected?
- What does the log say? Does the action actually receive a PATCH request?

Comment: My chrome console is delivering a PATCH request. And no my Rails routes do not say PATCH, they say PUT.. I'm using Rails `3.2.14`.. Perhaps I need to upgrade to get PATCH?

Comment: Yes, PATCH was introduced in Rails 4. You can either upgrade, or simply use PUT instead; this is merely a question of semantics - you gain nothing by using PATCH, except from maybe a fuzzy feeling ;)

Comment: Ah shucks.. I'm curious what the last version of Backbone.js was before PATCH was introduced.